# CI/CD Pipeline is failing for Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-synapse

I am getting below error when deploying Synapse CI/CD pipeline using Azure DevOps. The deployment was working fine until I added a few more notebooks and it started failing. Notebooks run fine on lower environment. All paths in the notebooks exist in higher environment. There is no concept of linkedTemplates in Synapse. I thought it was failing due to the length of ARMtemplate has exceeded.

Below is the error log, I have removed subscription name and resource group name and pipeline names.

```
2022-07-06T01:53:27.9739484Z Error during execution: Error: Failed to fetch the deployment status {"code":"400","message":"CreateOrUpdateNotebook failed: [statusCode from ADF:BadRequest, ErrorMessage: {\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"The document creation or update failed because of invalid reference ''.\",\"target\":\"/subscriptions//resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/workspace-02/notebooks/SilverToGoldPipeline\",\"details\":null,\"error\":null}, workspace: workspace-02, notebook: SilverToGoldPipeline, ArtifactId: ]"}
2022-07-06T01:53:27.9811549Z ##[error]Encountered with exception:Error: Failed to fetch the deployment status {"code":"400","message":"CreateOrUpdateNotebook failed: [statusCode from ADF:BadRequest, ErrorMessage: {\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"The document creation or update failed because of invalid reference ''.\",\"target\":\"/subscriptions/<>/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/workspace-02/notebooks/SilverToGoldPipeline\",\"details\":null,\"error\":null}, workspace: workspace-02, notebook: SilverToGoldPipeline, ArtifactId: ]"}
2022-07-06T01:53:27.9954864Z ##[section]Finishing: Synapse deployment task for workspace: Stage
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was because I had to create the Apache Spark pool first, before deploying.
Apparently, the deployment was not creating it automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Spark pool creation is must when we have notebook, as the Azure document suggested:
"Prepare pools before you migrate artifacts. If you have a SQL script or notebook attached to pools in the development workspace, use the same name for pools in different environments."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. The issue was that parameters file for higher environment was missing values for the pipelines. When we publish from master/main branch, if a new notebook is added and it is parameterized then an entry is created in the parameters file.